# How to view the code when no method/function is visible?

Tags: r, package

This question is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19226816/how-can-i-view-the-source-code-for-a-function). I am trying to figure out what the function does, but I still cannot see the source code of `SharpeR:::as.markowitz`.
I tried, without success:

```
getAnywhere("as.markowitz")
  getS3method("as.markowitz")
  methods("as.markowitz","SharpeR")
  methods(class="as.markowitz")
  methods("as.markowitz")
```

Is there other ways to see the source?

Comment: Try adding a dot then tab, after SharpeR:::as.markowitz to see if any methods are autocompleted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because methods for `as.markovitz` are not registered properly in the package namespace. Normally, this should work:

```
with(asNamespace("SharpeR"), methods("as.markowitz"))
```

Use `ls` to list all the functions in the package, and `get` to show the code:

```
ls(asNamespace("SharpeR"), all = TRUE)
get("as.markowitz.default", asNamespace("SharpeR"))
```